# Procedure for cloning Git repos that use subtree

Tags: git, subtree

I'm using Git's subtree command to pull a couple of libraries in to a project.

If I then clone the project in the normal way, I end up with all the code that I need, but I lose the subtree relationships - in the clone there is no remote for each of the libraries, and there is no -push branch for either of them.

What's the best way to re-establish this connection?

Is it sufficient to do

```
git remote add <lib> <remote-url>
git fetch <lib>
```

If I was adding the library for the first time I'd follow that with:

```
git subtree add -P <local/lib> --squash "<lib>/master"
```

This doesn't work when the local directory already exists though, which of course it will when you've cloned a project that has already had the library added to it.

Is there anything else that one should do in this situation, to ensure that subsequent git subtree merge and git subtree split commands to the expected thing?

Comment: `git subtree` isn't a standard git command ...

Comment: "An experimental alternative to the git-submodule command" -- https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that I have in the past re-created that relationship was by doing a subtree merge.

```
git pull -s subtree <lib> master
```

even if there is nothing to merge in/pull it should simply return without doing anything. Feel free to add `--squash` to the above pull so that you don't pull in any remote history.

Comment: This isn't the subtree pull, it is using git subtree merge technique and it can't be used to push the upstream changes.

Answer (score 9):

I had very similar issue

Here is how I created the subtree at first

```
git remote add -f sub_project url_to_remote_repository/project.git
git merge -s ours --no-commit sub_project/master
git read-tree --prefix=sub/project/ -u sub_project/master
git commit -m "Added subtree merged in sub/project"
```

and to get changes from the "project" repo, I was doing

```
git pull -s subtree sub_project master
```

Now, I pushed my local repository to github
and from another machine I cloned my github repository
At that point, I got all the expected file in sub/project ... so that's great.
But no more remote, and relation with sub/project.
So I did the following

```
git remote add -f sub_project url_to_remote_repository/project.git
git merge -s ours --no-commit --squash sub_project/master
git pull -s subtree sub_project master
```

And that worked fine. Now I am able to manage the subtree from that cloned repository as before

```
git pull -s subtree sub_project master
```

Note:

1) in our project, before we were using git submodules which was really not good for our users. That's why we switched to git 's subtree system.
2) I had some weird errors when doing those operations on Windows machine (using git version 1.7.9.msysgit.0 ), and the same operations were successfully on linux.
So now, to manipulate the subtree, I often use linux (and if I have any error, I try the same on linux).

Hope this can help.

Comment: I don't understand how the sub-directory prefix mapping is re-established in the sequence of commands you have described after a fresh clone. Shouldn't there be a "sub/project" somewhere in the commands?

Comment: When I tried the merge command above it tried to merge everything into the top-level of my project. This command seemed to work though: " git merge --squash -s recursive -Xsubtree=sub/project --no-commit tracking_branch"

Comment: Actually this worked even better: "git merge --squash -s ours -Xsubtree=sub/project --no-commit tracking_branch"

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this question while migrating a project from using submodules to subtrees and ended up using neither (at least not directly, anyway) - I am now using the [git-subrepo](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo) tool.

It solves this problem by adding a .gitrepo file at the root of each subtree. The .gitrepo file contains tracking information, including the remote URL, and is then included in subsequent clones. This really simplifies things and the only complication is that git-subrepo has to be separately installed on each development machine (though the repository is still usable without it).